# Ionic 2: tried accessing the FileTransfer plugin but it's not installed

Tags: ios, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

We are developing an app which uses Native File Transfer plugin. But due to a weird issue we can not create the Test Flight / Release Build for iOS.

**Issue**:
Even after successful installation of the 'File Transfer' plugin we see the following error while running the app with

```
ionic cordova run ios -lc

console.warn: Native: tried accessing the FileTransfer plugin but it's not installed.
```

As we tap a button that invokes the `fileTransfer.download(..)` method - the app halts to perform without throwing any Error.

I have created a detailed post with logs and code at:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2110

Any help ??

Answer (score 2):

After a thorough brainstorming I found the answer -

My issue was that the FileTransfer object could be accessed from inside the `platform ready` function but not inside a `provider` - this too on **iOS** [ Android version is working correctly ]

Here is what I did:

As I need an instance of the `FileTransfer` inside the `provider` - I created a variable - and an updater method -

```
private fileTransfer: any;

public setFileTransferRef( param ){
   this.fileTransfer = param;
}
```

And as I could access the `FileTransfer` inside the `platform.ready()` - I instantiated the `FileTransferObject` right there and updated the `provider` as follows -

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        console.log('fileTransfer: ');   
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fileTransfer));
        //
        let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
        //
        this.mediaIOSProv.setFileTransferRef(fileTransfer);
        .....
        ....
```

- Where `mediaIOSProv` is the **Provider** responsible to download the zip.

I also placed with the `cordova.js` inclusion after `build/vendor.js` in the `index.html` - ( I came across some posts where developers reported that doing so solved their missing plugin issue ) - *Though there is no such official documentation*.

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

> Since the app successfully ran on iOS - I did not dare to change the
>   placement of `cordova.js`

What I presume is -

1: It would be best to create a `Provider` to store references of each Native Plugin instantiated within the platform ready - and use the references as and when needed

2: There might be some information missing, specially regarding iOS, about the `Ionic-Native Wrapper`

Any suggestion / discussion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
Run `ionic cordova platform add [platform]` then `ionic cordova build [platform]` and run in your device.
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the platform

1. ionic cordova platform rm android

And then add the Platform again

2. ionic cordova platform add android